# First steps using Facebook Graph API with an external aplication

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, access-token

I want to do an application with PHP that runs on a server and get information from certains public facebook pages. I'm extremely noob and there are a few concepts that I don't understand yet:

I'm reading the API page and I'm reading about different access tokens. I understand you receive them when users log in your app, but my app is external and no one is logging. ¿Does my server app need a token access too? ¿What kind of token? and ¿How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called `app_access_token` to query non-user resources. The app access token is made up of your App ID and App Secret in the form:

```
$access_token = APP_ID .'|'. APP_SECRET;
```

(where `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET` are defined in your code)

You can then query the Facebook API using the above `$access_token`.